What is fit-to-window under Zoom setting in Chrome dev tools? What is the difference between a normal zoom and the one offered by devtools?
I tried looking into this setting(which is under zoom dropdown) in other places but couldn't find any descriptive explanation. So, I would like to ask for some help on these questions.

Does selecting this setting, mean that Chrome itself will try to fit the webpage on mobile devices?
Does this only happen with devtools or Chrome will do it actively everytime a webpage opens?
Lastly, what is the difference b/w a normal pinch in & out zoom and the one that is available in devtools?

